# Creating a TFS Build Definition that can execute 2 Command Line tasks at the same time

Tags: .net, tfs, build-definition

I am wondering if it is possible to configure TFS to run two command line execution steps at the same time (each one targeting its own Agent). The reason for this is that we are trying to incorporate parallel testing for our windows app, and since it is not web based we are kind of faking our own parallel solution by splitting the tests into different groups. What we have right now is two separate build definitions that are kicked off at the same time. I want to move it into just one build definition and have the command line executions run at the same time.

Is this possible with TFS? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have [multi-phase build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/release-notes/2017/sep-15-team-services#build) run possibility only in VSTS at the moment. But you can use release management in TFS and use parallel agents, if you are using TFS 2017.1 or higher. If you are using TFS 2015.2 or above use [release management multiple environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/triggers#env-triggers) and set them to run parallel.

Comment: Is the second option essentially just a way to kick off two or more build definitions at the same time? I was hoping to have it all in one build definition so we can have all the artifacts and logs in one place, but I guess we can't because we are not using the latest version. We are running off of V15..

Comment: @Tree55Topz if you are using TFS 2015.2 or above you can use release management environments to achieve the parallel running. You can setup your build to generate artifact and once the build completes you can setup a release definition, that get automatically triggered with the newly available artifacts. This way once you queue the build it will build and create the package, then you can deploy it to your target using release management, then you can run parallel environments to get the test run parallel in the same release defintion

Comment: @Tree55Topz setting up functional test automation running tests parallel is discussed in this post by me http://chamindac.blogspot.com/2016/08/setup-test-farm-as-azure-vmsfor-tfs2015.html . Just to give you an idea how to run  parallel tasks using release management in TFS 2015 linked with a build

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's not able to run build tasks/steps in parallel through a vNext build pipeline for now.

There has been a related uservoice here and get stated:

> **Add ability to run build steps in parallel**
>
> https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/13481574-add-ability-to-run-build-steps-in-parallel

So you are not able to achieve this and track logs **in a single build definition**.

As a workaround, you could use the solution mentioned above, separate build definitions that are kicked off at the same time with the help of some 3-party extension--[Parallel Builds](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kneradovsky.viko-build-tasks). Or you could also take the advice of *ChamindaC*'s, using release management multiple environments to run them parallel.